# Рекурсивная функция возвращает 2 значения одно из них undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, рекурсия

Добрый день!

Есть функция, которая принимает многомерный массив объектов и ключ нужного объекта.

Цикл проходит по массиву и сравнивает ключ каждого объекта с нужным ключом, если ключи совпадают, то возвращает нужный объект, если нет, то вызывает рекурсивно функцию для дочернего элемента.

Проблема следующая: когда нужный ключ принадлежит дочернему объекту, функция возвращает 2 значения, 1 - нужный объект, 2 - undefined. Как выбрать только 1 значение?

```
function findNode(rootNodes: CheckboxTreeNode[], key: string): CheckboxTreeNode | undefined {
   for (let i = 0; i < rootNodes.length; i++) {
        if (rootNodes[i].key === key) {
            return rootNodes[i];
        } else {
            findNode(rootNodes[i].children, key);
        }
    }
    return;
 }
```

Пример входных данных: 
1 аргумент:

```
let nodes = [
    {label: 'Name1', key: 'name', checked: false, open: true, children: [
        {label: 'Name2', key: 'nam2', checked: false, open: false, children: [
            {label: 'Name3', key: 'na3', checked: false, open: false, children: [] },
            {label: 'Name4', key: 'na4', checked: false, open: false, children: [] }
        ] },
        {label: 'Name2', key: 'nam3', checked: false, open: false, children: [] },
        {label: 'Name2', key: 'nam4', checked: false, open: false, children: [] }
    ] },
    {label: 'Name33', key: 'name3', checked: false, open: true, children: [
        {label: 'Name43', key: 'name4', checked: false, open: false, children: [] }
    ] },
];
```

2 аргумент: key = 'name3'

Получить нужно объект у которого key совпадает с key который передан в аргументе.

Comment: ой вэй, тут все неправильно

Comment: так может расскажешь как сделать правильно, если тебе не сложно

Comment: добавь пример входных данных и пример того, что ты хочешь из них получить.

Comment: _как сделать правильно_ - нужно использовать значение, которое ты получаешь из рекурсии. Ты его не используешь сейчас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы  рекурсивно вызываете функцию, при этом мужественно игнорируете возвращаемое ей значение

```js
function findNode(rootNodes: CheckboxTreeNode[], key: string): CheckboxTreeNode | undefined {
  for (let i = 0; i < rootNodes.length; i++) {
    if (rootNodes[i].key === key) {
      return rootNodes[i];  // нашли нужный узел
    } else {
      // пытаемся искать рекурсивно
      let res = findNode(rootNodes[i].children, key);
      // если, что-то нашли, то возвращаем найденное
      if (typeof res !== 'undefined')
        return res;
    }
  }
  return;  // ничего не нашли
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это помогло, я пробовал уже записывать значение возврата рекурсии в переменную но не додумался сделать проверку. Спасибо вам еще раз

Comment: @Umis Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его как правильный